# Can we bound $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ without pcf theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, pcf-theory

One of the famous applications of pcf theory is that if $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$. I'm curious whether any weaker result with the same flavor can be gotten without pcf theory. It's a bit tricky to phrase this precisely, but here's one attempt: can the following result be proved in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without pcf theory?

> $(*)\quad$ Suppose $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal. Then there is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that for every cardinal-preserving set-generic extension $V[G]$ satisfying "$\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal" we have $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\kappa$.

Certainly $(*)$ is implied by Shelah's result, since if $V$ and $V[G]$ have the same cardinals they agree on $\aleph_{\omega_4}$. But in principle it seems like it could be much weaker.

I'd also be interested in pcf-free proofs of further weakenings of $(*)$; to me, the most natural weakening seems to be gotten by restricting attention to some particularly nice class of forcings. (Basically, that "tame" forcings can't move $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ too much while keeping it a strong limit.)

Comment: Shelah's original proof that the given power is less than $\aleph_{(2^{\aleph_0})^+}$ in his "Proper forcing" book is such an example, I think.

Comment: Somehow related question is part (1) of the following: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137318/some-questions-about-0-sharp-and-forcing-over-l

Comment: Here's a PCF free argument: suppose that $2^{\aleph_\omega}>\aleph_{\omega_4}$ while still being a strong limit cardinal. Then by a result of Shelah ZFC is inconsistent.

Comment: @Asaf so which of Shelah's 1100+ papers is that result in, again? (Or are you being funny? Can't quite tell :-)

Comment: The Shelah $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{(2^{\aleph_0})^+}$ argument is quite complicated and if you look at it, it contains many elements of the (later) pcf theory. On the other hand the Galvin-Hajnal $2^{\aleph_{\omega_1}}<\aleph_{(2^{\aleph_1})^+}$ has a reasonable proof.

Comment: @David: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2008-02-26

Comment: @PéterKomjáth I'm not familiar with the Galvin-Hajnal result, what's a good source for it?

Comment: @Noah: I have a vague, but good, memory of the Holz, Steffens, and Weitz's "Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic" as being a good textbook.