# Can Jensen's covering lemma be proven easier in generic extensions of L?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, constructibility

Jensen's covering lemma, stating that if there is no $0^\#$ in V, then some covering property holds true, has a very complex proof.

In any generic extension L[G] of L, $0^\#$ don't exist, so the covering lemma holds in it.

My question is, could the proof of covering lemma in L[G] be significantly simplified? Do we know such a simple proof?

Comment: Depending on what you've proved already, it could be simplified. The question is how much work you're willing to put "outside" the actual proof into perhaps more generalised lemmas.

Comment: This question was covered by this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137318/some-questions-about-0-sharp-and-forcing-over-l